# Redmine - how to add link only visible on the issues menu page of a specific project page?

Tags: redmine

Hello Redmine experts,

I want to include a link (to a javascript function) on the issues menu page of a given project. Suppose I have several projects, but this link will only be visible on the issues menu page of project A but not on project B, C, ... . This link should be visible on the top, where the other links exists (Overview, Activity, Roadmap, Issues, New Issue, etc.).

Can you tell me how can I achieve this? Maybe a plugin that is easy to install and to configure?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy if you familiarly with rails. There are a lot of good [manuals](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugin_Tutorial) for plugin creation for redmine. 

So you can try to do it yourself or hire someone to implement it for you if you can not.